# What would be the n and p values when calculating adjusted r-squared using scikit-learn and 10-fold cross validation?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression

I know the formula for adjusted r-squared is: adj_r2 = 1-(1-R2)*(n-1)/(n-p-1).
However, what would the correct values be for **n** and **p** when you get the r-squared score with cross-validation?

Code sample:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score

lin_reg_r2 = cross_val_score(estimator = lin_reg, X = X_train, y = y_train, scoring = 'r2', cv = 10)
print("R2: {:.2f} %".format(lin_reg_r2.mean()*100))
```

Comment: Do you need to calculate adjusted R^2 at all? Cross validation already penalizes models which are overly complex.

Comment: You can read more in [the user guide](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#cross-validation) for the sklearn implementation; the fitting consists of "splitting the data, fitting a model and computing the score...consecutive times" the scores are computed normally for each fold, and then can be averaged (or weighted averaged, other treatments, etc) by accessing the `scores` parameter of the fitted object

Comment: @NickODell cross-validation does not do anything like that.

Comment: @desertnaut It does if the increased complexity decreases model fit on out-of-sample data - which is the reason you'd care about model complexity at all.

Comment: @NickODell you don't need CV for something like that - a simple train/validation split would do this, too